# Automation for Android release build

Tags: android

I have ten Android projects in one folder. For each project, I can use `ant debug` to build it. So it is no problem to write a simple script to compile all these projects. I use Hudson to build these projects daily, and it works fine.

But now our project needs to go to release phase. So the compile command becomes `ant release`. For compiling a release project, I have to enter the password for the certificate every time during compilation. So I can't do the automation for release.

This compiling job kills me since I have ten projects that all need to interact with inputting the password.

How can I make the release build still be automatic?

Comment: here's a tutorial that automates the password input: http://helpmeco.de/2012/2/compiling-and-signing-android-release-apk-from-the-command-line .

Answer (score 31):

Assuming you're using recent Android tools, say v9 or v10.

If you look at `tools/ant/main_rules.xml` in the Android SDK directory:

```
<!-- called through target 'release'. Only executed if the keystore and
     key alias are known but not their password. -->
<target name="-release-prompt-for-password" if="has.keystore" unless="has.password">
    <!-- Gets passwords -->
    <input
            message="Please enter keystore password (store:${key.store}):"
            addproperty="key.store.password" />
    <input
            message="Please enter password for alias '${key.alias}':"
            addproperty="key.alias.password" />
</target>

<!-- called through target 'release'. Only executed if there's no
     keystore/key alias set -->
<target name="-release-nosign" unless="has.keystore">
    <echo>No key.store and key.alias properties found in build.properties.</echo>
    <echo>Please sign ${out.unsigned.file} manually</echo>
    <echo>and run zipalign from the Android SDK tools.</echo>
</target>
```

Searching the XML file for `has.keystore` reveals:

```
<!-- properties for signing in release mode -->
<condition property="has.keystore">
    <and>
        <isset property="key.store" />
        <length string="${key.store}" when="greater" length="0" />
        <isset property="key.alias" />
    </and>
</condition>
<condition property="has.password">
    <and>
        <isset property="has.keystore" />
        <isset property="key.store.password" />
        <isset property="key.alias.password" />
    </and>
</condition>
```

So I'd assume you have to pass in four defines to the build.xml: `key.store`, `key.alias`, `key.store.password`, `key.alias.password`.

And remember not to pass those defines on the command line for security reasons. :)

Answer (score 23):

**Gradle-based builds**

**1)** Create a `secure.properties` file to contain your passwords:

```
key.store.password=<your keystore password>
key.alias.password=<your alias password>
```

You probably don't want it under version control, which is why we're putting the passwords in a separate `*.properties` file.  If you don't mind having your passwords under version control, you can enter your passwords directly into `build.gradle`, but that's not recommended, so I'm not directly showing that.

**2)** Set up your `build.gradle` as follows:

```
Properties secureProperties = new Properties()
secureProperties.load(new FileInputStream("secure.properties"))

android {
    signingConfigs {
        release {
            storeFile file("<path to your keystore>")
            storePassword secureProperties['key.store.password']
            keyAlias "<alias name>"
            keyPassword secureProperties['key.alias.password']
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.release
        }
    }
}
```

And that's it.  `./gradlew assembleRelease` now builds and signs my APK without prompting for my password.

**Ant-based builds**

**1)** Create a `secure.properties` file to contain your passwords:

```
key.store.password=<your keystore password>
key.alias.password=<your alias password>
```

You probably don't want it under version control, which is why we're not putting the passwords in one of the existing `*.properties` files.  If you don't mind having your passwords under version control, put these two lines in `ant.properties` and you're done.

**2)** Create a `custom_rules.xml` file to tell the build system about your `secure.properties` file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="custom_rules" default="help">
  <property file="secure.properties" />
</project>
```

I'm not familiar with this build system, so I'm not sure about the `project` element's `name` or `default` properties, but I believe what I chose should work for everybody.

**2b)** Any recent version of the Android SDK tools should be good to go, but if for some reason your `build.xml` file doesn't contain the following, you should add it:

```
<import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />
```

And that should be it.  `ant release` now builds and signs my APK without prompting for my password.

Comment: Where do you create the custom_rules.xml?  Is this something that is checked into your version control?

Comment: @brianestey `custom_rules.xml` is in the project root, alongside `build.xml`.  I check it into version control.

Comment: +1 for the `secure.properties` file and the suggestion to leave it outside of revision control.  That is the ideal balance of convenience and security for this problem.

Comment: Hi this is for ant project.. can you explain a bit for gradle based android project? i have a same issue...

Comment: @iMDroid Funny timing -- I just migrated BatteryBot to use Gradle-based builds this very afternoon!  Thanks for reminding me that I should update this answer with the Gradle setup I just sorted out.

Comment: @iMDroid I updated the answer right before commenting to you -- the part at the top for "Gradle-based builds" is new!

Answer (score 8):

You can define your keystore configure in your project.properties in your project folder.
Just like this

> key.store=/path/to/your/keystore
>
> key.alias=yourkeyalias
>
> key.store.password=yourkeystorepassword
>
> key.alias.password=yourkeyaliaspassword

Comment: can i ask you something about your answer, it worked for me only if i have the key before.but how can i generate it automatically.

Comment: You can user the `$ keytool -genkey -v -keystore my-release-key.keystore -alias alias_name -keyalg RSA -keysize 2048 -validity 10000` to generate a keystore. The details is [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/publishing/app-signing.html)

Answer (score 1):

Just a note... I didn't want to set the passwords in a props file and by default your password will be echoed on the command line which is also a concern. Adding use of SecureInputHandler to you main_rules.xml works so that your password isn't exposed on the command line.

```
<target name="-release-prompt-for-password" if="has.keystore" unless="has.password">
    <!-- Gets passwords -->
    <input
            message="Please enter keystore password (store:${key.store}):"
            addproperty="key.store.password" >
        <handler classname="org.apache.tools.ant.input.SecureInputHandler" />
    </input>
    <input
            message="Please enter password for alias '${key.alias}':"
            addproperty="key.alias.password" >
        <handler classname="org.apache.tools.ant.input.SecureInputHandler" />
    </input>
</target>
```

Answer (score 1):

have a look at [this](http://www.androidengineer.com/2010/06/using-ant-to-automate-building-android.html) article, especially where it starts mentioning `key.store.password`. I've used it without troubles.

Basically you should create some `secure.properties` file local to your (build) machine, that has to be kept relatively safe, e.g. not accessible to everyone or not stored for everyone in source control. That file stores the passwords as properties with the right names, and it's imported into project ANT build file.