# Release and debug version of the application in Android. Two certificates

Tags: android, debugging, certificate, release

I have created release (exported) version of the app. That created problem that debug version uses debug certificate for signing and exported version uses different certificate.

- Is it possible that they both use the same release version certificate?
- If yes, then is it possible to save certificate password, so I don't have to type it every time I export (or compile) application?
- If this is not advised or impossible, then how do you deal with Android shouting about Failure [INSTALL_PARSE_FAILED_INCONSISTENT_CERTIFICATES] every time you want to install release app into device which already has debug app installed?
- And how do you deal with Android Google Maps API V2 not working with debug certificate, because AndroidManifest.xml has the key which works only with app signed with release certificate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can automate your build process with gradle or ant. Once you do that its easier to build the signed apk. Using the latest Android studio you can create multiple versions of the same build at a time.

This [question and its answers](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5334399/2219600) will help you resolve this .

Answer (score 1):

To answer.

1. If a app is signed with same certificate it won't cause any issue, and basically there can never be two version of same certificate. Second, yes by default sdk use debug certificate to sign your application , and while releasing its on you to choose which certificate to sign.
2. You can create a batch file with predefined command to Sign you application, all you need to do is
   a. release your application raw, withouht signing
   b. Use Jarsigner, and your custom made certificate to sign it
   c. Use Zipaligner to optimize it, you can easily club this command in a batch file (in windows)
3. This error shows up when, already installed same application carries a signature of different certificate then what you are trying to push again, so either you remove preinstalled app manually and install new one, or sing the new app with same certificate in push it into device.
4. You can very well integrate Google Maps APIv2 with debug key, all you need to do is to register your app with google using hash of  debug key and using generated key in your app.

Comment: 1. I know how it works by default, but how to change the default. 3. I know why is the error, but I asked how other deal with it. 4. I know but I was rather asking how to use different google maps certificate depending on app certificate type or how to use one release certificate always.

Comment: for error issue, only equation is to uninstall manually and install new version, there is no other way, you can never automate this process which let you app choose when to use debug key and and not, the most ideal thing which you can do if to have both keys in your string xml as constant, and use the proper one at proper time.

Comment: And what are others doing? Are they using release certificate always, or rather 2 certificates and batch/scripts/ant settings to have working app independent from which certificate was used?

Comment: Yes, using release certificate is a mandate if you want to route your app through google play, else its on you. by default all the sdks use your debug key as default unless you change your preference.

Comment: this is not what I asked :D I asked which approach is more popular between commercial application developers.